# How to initialise a instance of a class with current time as attribute

Tags: python, class, datetime, initialization

I'm defining a class that has a time attribute which, but default, is set as the current UTC time.

```
import datetime

class Timer:
    def __init__(self, time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
        self.time = time
        print('Instance created at', self.time)
        
        
a = Timer()
```

The problem is that once defined (or when it is imported, if it's within module), this attribute is set forever! All new instances of the class "inherit" the time from the class, evaluated when it was defined, instead of generating its own "current time" when `__init__` is called. Why isn't the function to obtaint current UTC time evaluated every time a new instance is created?

Comment: Duplicate of ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/10987432)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining the default kwarg for `time`, `time` is evaluated when the class definition object is added/interpreted see function `__defaults__`, an immutable tuple.

```
>>> class Timer:
...     def __init__(self, time = datetime.datetime.utcnow()):
...         self.time = time
...         print('Instance created at', self.time)
... 
>>> Timer.__init__.__defaults__
# notice how the date is already set here
(datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 19, 15, 22, 42, 639808),)
```

Whereas you're looking to evaluate it when the class object instantiates.

```
>>> class Timer:
...     def __init__(self, time = None):
...         self.time = time or datetime.datetime.utcnow()
...         print('Instance created at', self.time)
... 
>>> Timer.__init__.__defaults__
(None,)
>>> a = Timer()
Instance created at 2021-02-19 15:04:45.946796
>>> b = Timer()
Instance created at 2021-02-19 15:04:48.313514
```

Comment: This isn't a scoping issue, at least not in the sense that the term "scope" is usually used in Python. The issue is that a default argument value is evaluated at class definition time, not when the method is called.

Comment: Thanks! I have came up to an even simpler example that nicely showcases the issue you raise about how default arguments are fixed at the moment of the function definition: `def givemetime(time = datetime.datetime.now()): print(time)''. This function has exactly the same issue.

Comment: @Onturenio that is a great minimal example. `givemetime.__defaults__` would be evaluated on definition.